# Flutter Future returning instance of future

Tags: flutter

I am making an api call to receive data. When I make the call, I get back an instance of future. Why does this still return an instance of future instead of waiting for the data?

Here is my networking file

```
class NetworkHelper {
  NetworkHelper(this.url);

  final String url;

Future getSecureData(String token) async {
    http.Response response = await http.post(
      Uri.parse(url),
      headers: {
        HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader: token,
      },
    );
    var data = response;
    return data;
  }
```

Here is my Account Settings file

```
class AccountSettings extends StatefulWidget {
  const AccountSettings({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  static const String id = 'account_settings';

  @override
  State<AccountSettings> createState() => _AccountSettingsState();
}

class _AccountSettingsState extends State<AccountSettings> {
  var userData;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    getUserData();
  }

  Future getUserData() async {
    var token = await SecureStorage.getAccessToken();
    var jwttoken = 'JWT ' + token!;
    NetworkHelper networkHelper =
        NetworkHelper('http://localhost:8000/auth/users/me');
    userData = await networkHelper.getSecureData(jwttoken);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print(userData);
    return Scaffold(
```

Comment: You're saying that `print(userData)` prints "Instance of Future"?  That shouldn't happen; I would expect it to print `null` because `build()` will be called before `getUserData` finishes.  Are you sure that `userData` isn't set anywhere else?  It might help if you gave `userData` an explicit type (instead of letting it be implicitly `dynamic`), which help catch type errors.

Comment: This is odd. Could you make sure that the code is reflecting your current code, without any possible edits? Also, typing the `Future` would be helpful. `Future<MyType>`. Also, setting the type of `userData` should indicate problems before compiling the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `getSecureData` method is returning a Future with no type associated, so try including a type to the the Future such as

```
Future<SomeType> getSecureData() async {
    //..
}
```